# How do I make a bot status that has memberCount on it?

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I made a simple discord verify bot, but I want to make the bot status to watching **# people** verifying (the # is how many people in my server). I see some bots have it, but I don't know how to make it. Here is my current code for the bot status:

```
if (Object.keys(this.config.presence).length !== 0) {
        this.user.setPresence({
            game: {
                name: this.config.presence.name,
                type: this.config.presence.type
            },
            status: "online"
        }).catch(console.error);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first you need set interval command to update member.

You dont need use `this.user` for this operation. The previus answer method will display only [cached](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users) users, so its wrong way, because on bot start, you will has no users in this collection.

If you need display members on your own server you can do like this:

1. Get your guild BY ID
2. Get property `guild.memberCount`
3. Update it every 5 min

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
        setInterval(() => {
          targetGuild = client.guilds.get('GUILD ID HERE')
          if(targetGuild) {
              client.user.setPresence({ game: { name: targetGuild.memberCount + ' people verifying!', type: 'WATCHING' }, status: 'online'  })
                    .then(console.log)
                    .catch(console.error);
          }
    }, 1000 * 60 * 5);

});
```

> After bot start, this will update after 5 minutes.
>
> For test you can change  `}, 1000 * 60 * 5)`  to  `}, 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

`client.users.size` should return you all the users from all the guilds that the bot is into!

```js
if (Object.keys(this.config.presence).length !== 0) {
    this.user.setPresence({
            game: {
                name: client.users.size + ' people verifying!',
                type: this.config.presence.type
            },
            status: "online"
        }).catch(console.error);
    }
```

You can also find this at [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users) documentation.

Comment: Thx, it works but it only said watching 0 people verifying, is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: @Veinify are you sure there are more than zero people ?

Comment: client.users.size display only [chached](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users) users, so at start this is zero collection

Answer (score 0):

its as simple as:

```js
bot.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: `${bot.users.cache.size} members` , type: 'WATCHING'}, status: 'online' })
```