# How to make Discord guild members count in bot status?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

[Main part!!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAY9Z.png)[What I finally get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWYvP.png)
**Hi,guys,i try to make shows my discord guild members count in bot status, but I don't understand finally how to do it, there is code**

```
client.on('ready', () => {
     setInterval(() => {
       targetGuild = client.guilds.ca.get('GUILD ID HERE')
       if(targetGuild) {
          client.user.setPresence({ game: { name: targetGuild.memberCount + ' people verifying!', type: 'WATCHING' }, status: 'online'  })
                .then(console.log)
                .catch(console.error);
       }
     }, 1000 * 60 * 5);
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a bot status that has memberCount on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60225366/how-do-i-make-a-bot-status-that-has-membercount-on-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in your provided code you misspelled something:

**Wrong:**

```js
targetGuild = client.guilds.ca.get('GUILD ID HERE')
```

**Correct:**

```js
targetGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('GUILD ID HERE')
```

Also, if you do it this way, the status of the bot will **not** show the **total number** of members from **all servers**, but only from a **specific** server.

However, if you want to sum up **all members** from **every guild** the bot is in, you can get the total members like this:

```js
const totalMembers = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.memberCount).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);
```

Then you just have to set this to the bot's status and you're done! :)

---

#### References:

- [`<array>.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Sorry,i misspelled this think only when I write requesting my code everything allright.Help pls

Comment: Okay, but `const totalMembers = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.memberCount).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);` should work anyways